# Prove that a map is one-to-one if $G$ is finite group and $H$ and $K$ are its subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, group-actions, group-homomorphism

Okay, so I've been struggling with one problem lately. I know it must be something very obvious and the solution is right in front of me, but I just can't see it.
Let's get to the problem:

Let $G$ be a finite group.

If $H$ and $K$ are subgroups of $G$, then the map $f \mapsto f(H)$ is one-to-one correspondence between the set of $G$-set homomorphisms from $G/H$ to $G/K$ and the set of cosets $xK \in G/K$ such that $H \subseteq {}^{x}K$, where ${}^{x}K = xKx^{-1}, x \in G$. In particular. the $G$-sets $G/H$ and $G/K$ are isomorphic if and only if $H$ and $K$ are conjugate in $G$.

So, the first part seems to be very obvious. Let $\psi$ denote the map. Then we have to prove that $\psi(f) = \psi(g) \implies f = g$, where $f, g \in Hom(G/H, G/K)$. So let's start with that indeed. $\psi(f) = \psi(g) \iff f(H) = g(H)$. What should be the next step? My first thought was $\forall_{h \in H} f(h) = g(h)$, but that's clearly false.

Speaking of the second part, I am also stuck, but let me show you my thoughts on "$\impliedby$". Groups are conjugate, so $K = gHg^{-1}, g \in G$. From that we acquire that $gH = Kg$. Now we need to define a map that is an isomorphism of $G$-sets (bijective $G$-equivariant map). I suggest $tK \mapsto tKg = tgH$. That map is indeed $G$-equivariant, because: $\phi(g' \cdot tK) = g'tKg = g' \cdot tKg = g' \cdot \phi(tk), g' \in G$. But what about proving injectiveness and surjectiveness? How the conditions should look like?

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that $f(h)$ and $g(h)$ for $h\in H$ doesn't make sense, since $f,g$ are functions $G/H \to G/K$, what you want to show is that $\forall a\in G, f(aH)=g(aH)$. You should use the fact that $f$ and $g$ are $G$-set homomorphisms.

Answer (score 3):

Well, $f\in\hom_G(G/H,\,G/K)$ is not defined on elements of $G$ (or $H$), so writing $f(h)=g(h)$ makes no sense.
The given part of the corollary is correct.

Observe that, if $f$ is $G$-equivariant $G/H\to G/K$, then $f(H)$  already determines it all, because we must have
$$f(x\cdot H)\ =\ x\cdot f(H)$$
so, if $f(H)=f'(H)$ for some other $f'$, then they must agree: $f(xH)=f'(xH)$ for all $xH\in G/H$, hence $f=f'$.
Let $S:=\{x\in G:\,H\subseteq xKx^{-1}\}$. Then we still need to prove $f(H)=xK$ with $x\in S$, and that the map $\psi$ is surjective to $\{xK:x\in S\}$.

For an arbitrary coset $xK\in G/K$, its stabilizer subgroup is just ${}^xK\subseteq G$.
Since $f(H)\in G/K$, there is an $x\in G$ such that $f(H)=xK$, and because $f$ is equivariant, for any $h\in H$,
$$xK=f(H)=f(hH)=hxK\,\implies\,x^{-1}hx\in K\,\iff\,h\in {}^xK\,.$$

To prove surjectivity, let $x\in S$, and show that $f:=gH\mapsto gxK$ is a well-defined $G$-equivariant map $G/H\to G/K$.

For the corollary, let $f:G/H\to G/K$ be a $G$-set isomorphism with inverse $f^{-1}:G/K\to G/H$.
The statement says that $f(H)=xK$ for some $x\in S$, so that $H\subseteq {}^xK$, and the same is true for $f^{-1}$, hence $K\subseteq {}^yH$ for some $y$.
So using finiteness, both these must be satisfied with equalities.

Comment: I think that the condition for being $G$-equivariant map should look like this: $f(g \cdot xH) = g \cdot f(xH)$, where $g \in G, xH \in G/H$. I also don't seem to fully understand the moment when you jump from $f(H) = f'(H)$ to $f(xH) = f'(xH)$. Is it multiplying left-side by $x$ and then using the fact that $f$ is $G$-equivariant? If that's so, how do we even know that $f$ is $G$-equivariant? In addition, I think that between $f(H)$ and $f(hH)$ there should be $\implies$ sign, not equality. But maybe I just don't fully understand your approach to the problem.

Comment: Both $f$ and $f'$ were assumed to be $G$-equivariant, which indeed means $f(gxH)=g\,f(xH)$ for all elements $x,g\in G$. I basically claimed that the $G$-set $G/H$ is generated by its single element $H\in G/H$, which is easily seen by letting $x=1$ in the above. By $hH$ I meant $h\cdot H$, applied the action with element $h\in G$ to element $H\in G/H$, and of course $h\cdot H=hH=H$ since $H$ is a subgroup containing $h$.

Comment: We work with the two group actions on the two sets of cosets: $G\times G/H\to G/H,\ (g,xH)\mapsto gxH$ and $G\times G/K\to G/K,\ (g,xK)\mapsto gxK$. Based on the OP it should be clear that these are well defined maps (we can have $xK=x'K$ for distinct elements $x,x'$).